# Can I use an SQLite View as parameter to a rawQuery

Tags: java, android, sqlite, view

I'm attempting to add a few reports to my Android app. First, I defined them as Views in my SQLite database to make sure they work correctly. Here's one of them:

`CREATE VIEW r3_DNFs AS SELECT Epreuve, Dossard, STRFTIME('%H:%M:%S %d',TempsPassage) AS "Temps" FROM Coureurs WHERE Statut is "DNF" ORDER BY SUBSTR(Epreuve, 5) + 0 DESC, Dossard;`

Can I use the following to simplify my coding?

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Epreuve, Dossard, Temps FROM r3_DNFs",null);
```

Comment: As long as it is a valid sql statement for SQLite you can use it.

Comment: Thank you @forpas. That will make the correlated subquery that you created for me a lot easier to code.  This volunteer project of mine has been a great learning experience, thanks to people like you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `rawQuery` you can use any valid sqlite's statement but it should not be [terminated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.CancellationSignal).) (which doesn't contain the `;` symbol).

Comment: Even though the docs say the sql must not be `;` terminated, having a semicolon there works just fine. Anything after the first `;` will be ignored though.

Comment: I think in we can get error or not different behaviour on next android versions or on device of some vendor (because they can patch framework)- the executing of statement which contains `;` doesn't defined.